# What does "keen" in "keen intellect" mean?

Tags: meaning

> her keen intellect

What is the meaning of *keen* in the phrase?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keen is used in this sense as a stand-in for *sharp*.

See usage 1a at [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/keen), for instance.

The usage "keen" for "sharp" is fairly common: "a keen edge", "a keen blade", etc.

Answer (score 3):

Although this does not represent the typical meaning of *keen* (*eager* is the more usual interpretation), the etymology of the word shows that the word has kept its ancient meaning in this case, meaning "knowledgeable" or "skillful".

To quote the [Wiktionary page](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/keen):

> From Middle English kene (“bold,
>   brave, sharp”), from Old English cēne
>   (“bold, brave”), from Proto-Germanic
>   *kōnjaz (“knowledgeable, skillful, able”), from Proto-Indo-European
>   *g'enə-, *g'nō- (“to know”)